# message: "Http failure response for url 500 OK"

Tags: c#, angular, http-status-code-500

I am getting this error for the post request API call from angular service, after hosting the web API in GoDaddy. But it is working perfectly fine in my local machine. Can anyone please tell me what is goin wrong with my code.

[Snapshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Hdgp.png)
The error I am getting.

This is the Angular service

```
saveforpandl(paymenttdata1) {
  return this.http.post(this._urls.weburl + 'api/AallPandR/PostPaymentpandl/',  paymenttdata1);
}
```

C# code: This is the API backend method that I am calling from Angular

```
        [HttpPost]

        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostPaymentpandl(PaymentCreditDebitListVM paymentdata1)
        {
            try
            {
                if (paymentdata1.PaymentCreditList != null && paymentdata1.PaymentDebitList != null)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < paymentdata1.PaymentCreditList.Count; j++)
                    {
                        var acccode1 = (paymentdata1.PaymentCreditList[j].CreditToAccountId);
                        var acname1 = (paymentdata1.PaymentCreditList[j].CreditToAccountId);

                        var acccode = _db.MinorGroupMasters.Where(c => c.ID.ToString() == acccode1).Select(c => c.MinorGroupCode).FirstOrDefault();
                        var accnmae = _db.MinorGroupMasters.Where(c => c.ID.ToString() == acname1).Select(c => c.MinorGroup).FirstOrDefault();


                        tbl_AllReceiptsAndPayments prev2 = new tbl_AllReceiptsAndPayments()
                        {
                            VoucherType = paymentdata1.PaymentCreditList[j].VoucherType,
                            DebitORCredit = "Credit",
                            TransactionNumber = paymentdata1.PaymentCreditList[j].PaymentNumber,
                            AccountId = acccode,
                            AccountName = accnmae,
                            Amount = paymentdata1.PaymentCreditList[j].CreditAmount,
                            TransDate = Convert.ToDateTime(paymentdata1.PaymentCreditList[j].PaymentDate),
                            ChequeNumber = paymentdata1.ChequeNumber,
                            DDNumber = paymentdata1.DDNumber,
                            Narration = paymentdata1.Narration,
                            BranchId = 1,
                            CreatedOn = DateTime.Now,
                        };
                        await Task.Run(() => _db.tbl_AllReceiptsAndPayments.Add(prev2));
                        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

                    }


                    for (int j = 0; j < paymentdata1.PaymentDebitList.Count; j++)
                    {
                        var acccode1 = (paymentdata1.PaymentDebitList[j].DebitByAccountId);
                        var acname1 = (paymentdata1.PaymentDebitList[j].DebitByAccountId);

                        var acccode = _db.MinorGroupMasters.Where(c => c.ID.ToString() == acccode1).Select(c => c.MinorGroupCode).FirstOrDefault();
                        var accnmae = _db.MinorGroupMasters.Where(c => c.ID.ToString() == acname1).Select(c => c.MinorGroup).FirstOrDefault();

                        tbl_AllReceiptsAndPayments prev1 = new tbl_AllReceiptsAndPayments()
                        {
                            VoucherType = paymentdata1.PaymentDebitList[j].VoucherType,
                            DebitORCredit = "Debit",
                            TransactionNumber = paymentdata1.PaymentDebitList[j].PaymentNumber,
                            AccountId = acccode,
                            AccountName = accnmae,
                            Amount = paymentdata1.PaymentDebitList[j].DebitAmount,
                            TransDate = Convert.ToDateTime(paymentdata1.PaymentDebitList[j].PaymentDate),
                            ChequeNumber = paymentdata1.ChequeNumber,
                            DDNumber = paymentdata1.DDNumber,
                            Narration = paymentdata1.Narration,
                            BranchId = 1,
                            CreatedOn = DateTime.Now,
                        };
                        await Task.Run(() => _db.tbl_AllReceiptsAndPayments.Add(prev1));
                        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

                    }
                }
                return Ok(1);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                throw e;
            }

        }
```

Comment: The error is coming from the API server side, hard to tell from your front

Comment: Hi @javier_domenech, yes the error is from the API side. For the reference I have also attached the method from where I am getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error is in convertion of date time

```
Date = Convert.ToDateTime(receiptdata1.CreditList[j].ReceiptDate)
```

and it should be

```
DateTime Date = DateTime.Parse(receiptdata.CreditList[j].ReceiptDate,
CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(&quot;en-IN&quot;));
```

this may work